# Telegram bot Ошибка в сообщении

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Пытаюсь передать в сообщении бота текст с переменной из sqlite3, но печатает он её с  [('',)], если печатать только одну переменную то всё в норме. Пытался реализовать с +, но выдаёт ошибку: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str. Надеюсь объяснил понятно, в программировании новенький, надеюсь на быструю помощь

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text == 'Начнём подборку книг?': 
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет :)')
    elif message.text == 'Рандомную книгу':
        cursor.execute("SELECT Произведение FROM BOOK ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;")
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Советую прочитать тебе ' + result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В твоём случае надо писать result[0]. Т.к. при запросы возращается словарь

Comment: Ммм, чувак, кажется ты меня не понял. Бот выдаёт такой ответ: "Советую прочитать тебе [('Властелин колец',)]" Мне нужно убрать лишние знаки, а не сохранить :)  (Или я тебя не понял, прости за недопонимание)

Comment: bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Советую прочитать тебе ' + result[0])

Comment: Чувааааак, красавааа, сорян что не понял :D